# Как избежать дублирования "" при чтении из csv Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

В файле .csv в ячейке сохранен текст часть текста: `...<h1 style="text-align: center;">...` но при чтении из этого файла дублируются ковычки:

```
..."<h1 style=""text-align: center;"">...

with open("itog.csv", "r") as r:
for line in r:
    print(line)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избежать дублирования

P.S. пробовал чтобы изначально в ячейку записывалось `...<h1 style=\"text-align: center;\">...` не помогло...

Comment: Использовать модуль csv (если кратко)

Comment: он используется, что конкретно в нем использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csv файл:

```
;"<h1 style=""text-align: center;"">";
```

Читаем файл, в настройках ридера указываем, что разделитель ячеек (`delimiter`) - точка с запятой, ячейки со строковыми значениями обернуты в кавычки (`quotechar`), кавычки внутри кавычек дублируются (`doublequote=True`). Примерно так должны выглядеть настройки для чтения csv файлов, созданных, например в Microsoft Excel. Для csv созданных в других программах настройки могут отличаться - например, разделителем может быть не точка с запятой, а запятая.

```
import csv

with open('itog.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', doublequote=True)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Вывод:

```
['', '<h1 style="text-align: center;">', '']
[]
```

Документация: [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Спасибо, огромное при огромное)) час как минимум убил..

Answer (score 2):

Небольшое дополнение к [ответу @insolor tired of this drama](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1064193/211923) - у модуля csv есть метод [csv.Sniffer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer), позволяющий автоматически подобрать настройки CSV - `диалект`.

[Пример из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer):

```
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
# ... process CSV file contents here ...
```

PS [как заметил @insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064186/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-csv-python/1064298?noredirect=1#comment1823275_1064298) - иногда Sniffer ошибается, поэтому надо проверять насколько правильно он определил диалект

Comment: Метод есть, но на практике он часто неверно определяет параметры диалекта.

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду)