# Дублирование кавычек во время сохранения в csv Python

Tags: python, csv

Час добрый
Имеется следующий текст:

```
"1","хорошая погода"
```

При сохранении в csv при помощи следующего кода:

```
list = [
    '"1","хорошая погода"',
]
for line in list:
    with open(f'result/test.csv', 'a', newline='', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow([line])
```

Если открывать в excel, то визуально все выглядит так:

```
"1","хорошая погода"
```

Однако если прочитать данный файл:

```
with open('result/test.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

В консоль выпадет сообщение:

```
"""1"",""хорошая погода"""
```

Подскажите как исправить сохранение, чтобы двойные кавычки не дублировались(и вся конструкция повторно не записывалась в кавычки). Знаю что можно при чтении просто дописать replace('"""', '"') и так же для "", но это не вариант\

EDITED
Метод открытия файла написал не тот, использую следующее:

```
info = pd.read('test.csv', headee=None, names=['Class', 'Text'], encoding='cp1251')
```

Comment: Убрать кавычки вокруг строк ваших данных, сделать строки данных кортежами или списками: `list = [("1","хорошая погода"),]`

Comment: @insolor Сейчас отредактирую текст сверх, посмотрите снова пожалуйста

Comment: Т.е. вы данные в list через pd.read загружаете? Нужно конкретно понимать, откуда у вас такой list берется. Если вы его сами в код вбиваете, то см. первый комментарий. Если он такой получается при чтении из csv, то нужно править параметры чтения, например delimiter может не совпадать с тем, что в файле фактически (похоже на то, что при чтении указан указан разделитель `";"`, а по факту в файле используется `","`)

Comment: @insolor list просто как пример того, что при сохранении csv файла данные построчно берутся из списка. Подскажите как исправить сохранение, чтобы сохранялось без дублирования кавычек? Нашел данную статью https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064186/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-csv-python
Но она помогает устранить кавычки при чтении файла, но не при записи

Comment: Тогда исправляйте исходный список. У вас фактически сейчас не набор ячеек в списке, а одна ячейка, в которой записано `"1","хорошая погода"`. Из-за этого при записи в csv и дублируются кавычки.

Comment: @insolor Ваше замечание про разделитель помогло, спасибо большое

Comment: Если значение поля содержит символ кавычки, разделителя или конца строки, то всё значение берётся в кавычки, а символ кавычки удваивается. Но при создании writer'а вы можете переопределить символ кавычки (параметр `quotechar`) на отличный от `"`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Спасибо за ответ, уже разобрался)